# Domains and cookie accessibility

Tags: cookies

If I am hitting www.foo.com and am writing some cookies there, will I have access to those cookies if I hit the same code base from www2.foo.com?  Or does the cross-domain cookie security come into play with sub-domains as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set a cookie's domain as `.example.com`, it'll be available across all subdomains. If you set the domain as `www.example.com`, it'll only be accessible to the `www` subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies set for foo.com will be accessible by sub-domains.  Sub-domain cookies are not accessible by other sub-domains.